# Passing parameters thru CloudPageURL() function in Ajax call

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, cloudpagesurl

I am using Ajax to call a AMPScript code resource; I am using CloudPageURL() function to encrypt the parameters being passed.

The code is working properly when passing hard-coded values as parameters but I don't find the way to pass JS vars.

I was thinking about using AMPScript vars using a SSJS function to pass JS vars to AMPScript vars using "Variable.SetValue("@email",p1)" function but it didn't work either.

This is my code working properly. Now I need to replace the hard-coded values with JS variables.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      const elm = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(elm);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = elm.Message;
    }
  };
 
  
 var expression = "%%=CloudPagesURL(2344)=%%";
  
  xhttp.open("POST", expression, true);
  
  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  
  xhttp.send("firstname="+firstName+"&lastname="+lastName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to observe the execution context of your code. Ampscript and SSJS gets executed in the backend, and hence you can't pass JS variables into the *CloudPagesURL* function, as you try in your example.

What you need to so is follow these steps:

1. Create a Cloud Page code resource, which will receive your parameters in the URL, and fetch it using [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) function
2. This code resource should be responsible for your data processing towards SFMC utilising e.g. [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) function
3. Reference the URL of this code resource in your front end JS code
4. Append the parameters you want to pass to SFMC as URL parameters

Please also check out this blog post: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-enhance-your-forms-with-ajax-and-ampscript/ describing the above in more details.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your response. So following your comments I understand we have two options: 1.- To use CloudPageURL() is this context not passing any paramters and 2.- To use by default code passing URL parameters. Is option 2 secure ? If you need to pass PII info for example, will  this second option be secured ? thanks !

Comment: @EnriqueDiaz - regardless, all the data you will be sending, will be initiated from front end javascript, these PII will always be visible to the visitor. So using CloudPageURL will not hide it. When it comes to passing it to code resource, please ensure SSL is applied to the domain of the Cloud Pages on that MID, so your connection utilizes https.

Comment: Yes, you are fully right. Thanks !

Comment: I just wanted to share with you my last findings: we can combine CloudPagesURL() function with the send(body parameters) for passing to the resource code page both parameters: front-end open parameters + MC user context parameters. I did a test with the code below (I have modified it with the right version) and worked properly. Best